# How to change the bottom border color of a Vuetify v-overflow-btn?

Tags: css, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm actually building a website in nuxt.js using Vuetify. I have created a menu based on one `v-overflow-btn`, one `v-text-field` and one `v-btn`.
[Here is what my menu looks like actually.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf2hM.png)

Cause I'm a little bit maniac, I would like to change the bottom border color of my `v-overflow-btn` to match all the different dividers color bar of my menu. By default, the color is black.

I already tried to define my own CSS in the style section as below:

```
<style>
  v-overflow-btn {
    border-color:grey !important;
  }
</style>
```

But nothing changes...

Could someone behelp me to change this border color? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
<style>
  .v-overflow-btn .v-input__slot::before {
    border-color: grey !important;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Working great! Thanks a lot :)
I had tried the `.v-input__slot` but I had forgotten the `::before` --'

Comment: You are welcome. Btw if you accept this answer with the tick button next to it you'll earn few reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the deep selector in case someone else is having this issue.

```
.nbb >>> .v-input__slot:before  {
  border-color: white !important;
}
```